# How can I use the stock Android settings app on an LG G2?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, lg, lg-g2

I've upgraded my LG G2 (AT&T D800) to Lollipop 5.0.2 and have been wanting to try out some new settings/features of the settings app. In particular I've been wishing I had the search feature to find a setting. But alas, LG has some custom settings app that seems to be missing some settings or just has things organized differently so it's hard to follow instructions for changing Lollipop settings.

Does the regular stock Android (AOSP) settings app exist on my phone? Or can I install it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can, but you shouldn't. Install a custom ROM instead.

Long answer: Some features in your stock ROM may be dependant on that ROM's Settings app, because it might contain some preferences that affect them. Your Settings app may be missing some Lollipop settings simply because the ROM doesn't support them. You can try to install the AOSP Settings app, but there's no guarantee it will fully work because of those two issues. A solution to that would be to flash an AOSP (or AOSP-like) ROM, such as [CyanogenMod](http://cyanogenmod.org), probably the most popular one out there.